# How to turn off grep line buffering

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, asterisk

i am trying to pluck a phone number from an asterisk log in real time. i am using tail to do so, the problem is from what i understand is that grep uses line buffering and since tail isn't ending it waits till tail flushes but i need the number as it comes through system. Here is my code

```
    tail -f /var/log/asterisk/messages | grep  @default | awk -F ' ' '{ print $11 }' | awk -F  '[^0-9]*' '{ print $2 }'
```

i also want to make sure that the pattern it returns is also a 10 digit number as it stands it is return smaller 1-6 digit numbers.

Thanks in advance

TrueY:
  that is close: here is a an example the data that im trying to filter

```
    [Jul 17 12:11:00] VERBOSE[13992] logger.c: [Jul 17 12:11:00]     -- Executing [h@default:1] DeadAGI("Local/91201xxx0249@default-abb1,2", "agi://127.0.0.1:4577/call_log--HVcauses--PRI-----NODEBUG-----0-----CANCEL----------") in new stack
```

what i am wanting to do is pull the 10 digit phone number immediately before the '@default'

Comment: I don't think you understand "line buffering." Grep buffers one line at a time, and checks and prints it (if it matches) as soon as it sees the newline. With many classes of regexes, it's impossible to tell if the line matches until that newline anyway.

Comment: Also, `grep | awk` is redundant, as is two `awk`s; use `tail -f ... | awk -F ' ' '/@default/{split($11,a,/[0-9]+/);print a[2]}'`. And unless you want two spaces to create an empty field between them, drop the `-F ' '`.

Comment: @Kevin: I think in your solution $11 is splitted by a number, but in OPs example line should splitted by a non-number (if I interpret his goal well).

Comment: @TrueY Right, just add a `^` to the front of the character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MODIFIED#2**

Actually `tail` is not real time. It checks for new values in every 1 sec by default (change by `-s` option).

I improved [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900873/kevin)'s answer a little bit. I assume that the 12th field (and not 11th) contains the number ("DeadAGI("Local/91201xxx0249@default-abb1,2"," - it is not 10 digits! I assume it is):

```
tail -f /var/log/asterisk/messages | 
awk 'match($12, /[^0-9]91([0-9]{10})@default/, a) {print a[1]}'
```

This will only print if the line contains "@default" and the 12th filed contains exactly 10 continuous digits.

Comment: @Iz3k34l: I improved my answer. The number should be extracted from the "DeadAGI(" part? It is the 12th field, isn't it? Also it is continuous 10 digits or there are non digit characters between?

Comment: there are actually 12 continuous digits, the 9 being an unused character that is later stripped in another process and then the 1 which again is stripped in another process so all im concerned with is the 10 digits following the 9 and the 1. the number doesn't always follow "DeadAGI" but does always precede the text "@default" in some manner. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Iz3k34l: Ok! Modified accordingly. If it is not determined which field contains this value, change `$12` to `$0` and it will parse the whole line, not just the 12th field.

Comment: @Iz3k34l: the pleasure is mine!